# Why am i getting this error of missing Google Play Services on my HTC?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have downloaded the Geodetection sample app (sample app for Geofencing) from the official android site: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

My HTC has Android OS version 2.3.5.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.geofence"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!--
        Requests address-level location access, which is usually
        necessary for geofencing
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true" >

        <!-- The app's entry point -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_geofence" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!--
                    This activity is triggered when the system
                    tries to start the app's main activity
                -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <!--
                    This activity should be linked to the app's Launcher icon
                 -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.android.geofence.ReceiveTransitionsIntentService" android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the what I am getting when trying to import Google Play Services...a greyed out checkbox:

[image]
The application does load successfully on the emulator and the HTC device as well. The moment I click the "Register Geofence" button, the runtime error is thrown.

[image]
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Somehow I have succeeded to add Google Play Services as a reference. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Here is my log cat:
[image]

What is the issue here? And how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you import the `google-play-services_lib` in your workspace? and included that in as a library in your project? 
**EDIT :** 
How to import

Open Android ADT . File > Import > Andriod > Import existing android project > 
Import the google-play-services_lib from /sdk/extras/google/google-play-services_lib

After importing that project resolve the errors if you are getting any. 
And then 
Right click on your project > Properties > Android > Under Library tab > Add and select the project from your workspace.

Comment: Can you guide me here how to import that...may be i am doing it the wrong way?

Comment: That's what I am up to right now but what I am having is a greyed colour disabled checkbox appearing in the Import Projects wizard. Why is that? Any clue?

Comment: Got the solution. That lib was already in my workspace as a project. I deleted that and imported it once again in my actual project.

Comment: I have imported the library but still I am getting the same runtime error. Why is that?

Comment: Have you added?  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` Also What version of SDK and Android you are using?

Comment: I really appreciate your feeback here but first i need to get rid of this greyed out, disabled checkbox in android Import Projects wizard in eclipse(screenshot attached in question). Can you please help me to get rid of this first please. Thanks

Comment: First of all you have to update your SDK and google play libraries to latest version. After doing that you have to remove the `google-play-services_lib` from your workspace (delete the folder of that too from your workspace) and then import fresh newly downloaded (updated) library version.

Comment: Currently following your guidelines:

Comment: Done with them. Please check for the latest update in my question. The Google Play Services are still not included according to the emulator.Although, I was successful in importing the Google Play Services from ADT libs folder into my application via the wizard.

Comment: What is the issue now you are facing?

Comment: Same issue! Please check the screenshots. There is a latest edit in my question. The logcat states: Google Play Service resources were not found. Check your project configuration to see whether resources are included are not.

Comment: Add this in your manifest file under the **<application>** <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: That has already been added. Even then the runtime error is there as shown in the logcat (see screenshot in question).